# how to do one link attribute with more href address in it?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

code:

`<a href='http://$websites' target='_blank'>$websites</a>`;

$websites is a **string**;

the code on the html looks :

`<a target="_blank" href="http://WWW.GOOGLE.COM WWW.FACEBOOK.COM ">WWW.GOOGLE.COM WWW.FACEBOOK.COM </a>`

and **i want** this to be two links, how can i do this? the $websites is coming from a textarea; when it's just one link it's ok, but if i have two links, one per row then i don't know how to do this. please help

Comment: You have to have two `<a>` elements, one for the first URL and one for the second.

Comment: and how can i do this, because some times i have only one link, and sometimes i have two or three max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$website= explode(" ", $websites);
for($i = 0; $i < count($website); $i++){
   echo "<a href='http://".$website[$i]."' target='_blank'>".$website[$i]."</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
$websites = explode(' ', $websites);
foreach($websites as $site){
    echo '<a href="http://'.$site.'" target="_blank">'.$site.'</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks very much Adam, but i need all the links to be in one line separated by a space with foreach i got new line foreach link

Answer (score 0):

well, this maybe an alternative solution

have 2  links with one of them `display:none`

when you click one of them, click the other one by `$('.hidden_link').click();`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$linkArray = explode("\n", $websites);

foreach($linkArray as $link) {
    echo('<a href="http://'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>');
}
```

Comment: -1 for incorrect code (wrong argument order, unnecessary `for` loop, wrong check within the loop, mixed concatenation).

Comment: Now the code should look much better. Sorry for mixing things up and making such mistakes. But what is meant with "wrong check within the loop"?

Comment: It looks only slightly better. The "wrong check within the loop" means you have incorrect condition executed with every pass of the loop, which will result in 1) infinite loop (the biggest problem in your code), 2) unnecessary counting of array elements (just bad practice, since you do not change the array during the loop). You can get rid of both by using `foreach` loops instead of `for`. `echo` is not a function, so brackets are not strictly necessary (but they look nicer, though). The other problem is "`'\n'`" (for two reasons).

Comment: ahh okay I forgot to write the $i < count($linkArray). The other one with the \n is to explode the links when a break occured and not a space. But we don't know now how the textfield with the links look like, so it's just an example when a break is used to seperate the links.

Comment: By the "_problem with `'\n'`_" I meant, that you are not exploding the string by "break". You are exploding it by two-char-long string (`'\n'` string has two characters, but `"\n"` would have one - the difference results from the kind of quotes). Overall, after fixing these 3 major problems and two smaller issues your code should be okay.